# How to check if a device is AD joined or Azure AD joined/registered?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I need to check if my device is local Domain Joined or Azure AD joined/registered. How to check this? I tried [NetGetJoinInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmjoin/nf-lmjoin-netgetjoininformation) and could not get anything for Azure AD joined scenario. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I need to check if my device is local Domain Joined or Azure AD joined/registered. How to check this?

You could get the answer from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/device-management-azuread-joined-devices-setup).

> To verify whether a device is joined to an Azure AD, you can review the Access work or school dialog on your device.
>
> Alternatively, you can run the following command: **dsregcmd /status**
> On a successfully joined device, AzureAdJoined is Yes.

[image]

Comment: How do I differentiate between Joined and Registered here?

Comment: The linked document tells how to join, not how to find the join status programatically.Link to the external doc for an answer is not preferred, links break, best to include the relevant content in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

A machine is "Azure AD Joined" if it was registered using an Azure AD email. A machine is "Azure AD Registered" if it was already logged in with a personal account and then 'connected' to AzAD.

To check which one, the simple method (not 100% accurate) would be to check the username in use under Settings -> Accounts -> Your Info. Is this a personal (registered) or corporate (joined) account?  Also check "Access work or school" - it will say connected if it is.

The accurate method, is as follows:

dsregcmd /status

If you are connected to AzureAD, towards the top it will say "AzureADJoined: Yes".

What type?  The second block (device details) has the answer...

If you are "Registered", then the format of the page is different and there will be an entry "WorkstationDeviceID".

If you only see "DeviceID: xxxxx" then you are "Joined".

Thanks to and more details here: https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0001597

Answer (score 0):

From [Network Management Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/netmgmt/network-management-functions#azure-active-directory-join-information-functions) there seems to be Azure Active Directory Join Information Function
`NetGetAadJoinInformation`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tom Sun MSFT's answer, if you have access to Azure portal and **not** able to login into the machine to run the dsregcmd /status command, then you can run that command from:

1. Click on the VM in Azure
2. In the left hand menu click "Run Command"
3. Click "RunPowerShellScript"
4. Then run dsregcmd /status remotely without logging in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a batch/cmd/script:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %A IN ('dsregcmd /status ^| findstr /I "AzureAdJoined"') DO (SET AzureAdJoined=%A)
IF /I %AzureAdJoined%==yes (azure ad join SUCCESS so do thing here) ELSE (azure ad join FAILED so do thing here)
```

This searches *dsregcmd* output for just the field we are interested in (AzureAdJoined) then the FOR/tokens takes just the value/answer (yes or no) & puts it in variable %a, then DO SET at end puts %A variable into another variable more aptly named then verifies if yes output/echo yes, replace the echo no with something we’d do if the azure domain join failed like put up message or put it in a log, etc.