# Determine if machine is joined to AzureAD

Tags: winapi, credential-providers

With AzureAD you can join a machine so that it belongs to Workgroup or a regular domain, and then it can also be joined to AzureAD.

Something like joeblow.onmicrosoft.com, with maybe a username like joe@joeblow.onmicrosoft.com

Is there a Win32 API to determine if it is joined? Is there a registry key to search?

Closest I can find is

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CloudDomainJoin\JoinInfo\FDAFC88ANDENOUGHTOMAKE40CHARS` with a Property named `UserEmail` and a value of `joe@joeblow.onmicrosoft.com`.  It also has other key value pairs like TenantId (a guid), ldpDomain = login.microsoft.net, and device display name which is the name of my laptop. I'm at home and am not joined to a domain...so normal login is to workgroup for the domain.

Is there a Win32 API to determine if it is joined? Is there a registry key to search?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a device is AD joined or Azure AD joined/registered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816554/how-to-check-if-a-device-is-ad-joined-or-azure-ad-joined-registered) - Tagged c#, but irrelevant (gist: `dsregcmd /status`).

Comment: Yes, helpful. Will be looking at `NetGetAadJoinInformation()`

Comment: yes, *NetGetAadJoinInformation* this is correct api here. by fact this is forward to [*DsrGetJoinInfo*](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52818.azure-ad-join-behind-the-scene.aspx) in *dsreg.dll*. here exist some similar undocumented api. like `HRESULT DsrIsDeviceJoined(BOOL*, BOOL*)` which search for certificate in *MY* local machine store with "1.2.840.113556.1.5.284.7" extension

Comment: Can different users with or without admin privileges (but I think I'm assuming admin) join different AzureAD domains?  For instance one joins joe.onmicrosoft.com and the other joins blow.onmicrosoft.com?

Comment: think that no. all information is stored per machine (say HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key, certificate in *CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE* ) not per user. say *IdpDomain* and *TenantId* stored in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CloudDomainJoin\JoinInfo\<guid>* where *<guid>* from certificate [*1.2.840.113556.1.5.284.2*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dvrj/850786b9-2525-4047-a5ff-8c3093b46b88) extension. however - for what this need ? what is target goal ?

Comment: now *NetGetAadJoinInformation* ( = *DsrGetJoinInfo*) search certificate in local machine *My* store with *"1.2.840.113556.1.5.284.7"* extension == 1. then read guid from *1.2.840.113556.1.5.284.2* extension (must be 16 byte *X509_OCTET_STRING* ) and look in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CloudDomainJoin\JoinInfo\<guid>* (guid without {}) here read *IdpDomain*, *TenantId*, *UserEmail*, then used *TenantId* for read *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CloudDomainJoin\TenantInfo\<TenantId>* - *DisplayName*, *MdmEnrollmentUrl*, .. all per machine

Comment: Target goal is a credential manager for machine login and to be able to detect at runtime if user is logging into AzureAD without requiring AzureAD\joe@joeblow.onmicrosoft.com ... and just needing joe@joeblow.onmicrosoft.com and being smart about substituting AzureAD for the domain automatically.